# SASS Customize Class Names with Variables

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to customize the variables in SASS?
For example:

```
.m-b-{$number} {
    margin-bottom: $number;
}
```

If I give class="m-b-50" to an element, it should take margin-bottom 50. I just want to know if it is possible with SASS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the help of `variable interpolation or variable substitution` which uses `#{}` for variable substitution in SASS and `mixins` which is a block of code just like function.

***Interpolation*** is the process of evaluating an expression or a string containing one or more variables, yielding a result in which the variables are replaced with their corresponding values.

Simple example of interpolation and set values to the css property in SASS:

> ```
> $number:60;
> $n: 20px;
>
> .m-b-#{$number}{
>   margin-bottom: #{$number}px;
>   margin-top: $n;
> }
> ```

To create customize class names, will use mixins:

> ```
> @mixin margin-class($side, $number) {
>   $firstLetter: str-slice($side, 0, 1);
>   .m-#{$firstLetter}-#{$number}{
>      margin-#{$side}: #{$number}px;
>   }
> }
>
> $margins: (10, 20);
> $sides: ("top", "right", "bottom", "left");
> @mixin generate-margin(){
>    @each $margin in $margins{
>       @each $side in $sides{
>         @include margin-class($side, $margin);
>       }
>    }
> }
>
> @include generate-margin();
> ```

Here, `generate-margin()` will get executed which will call `margin-class()` for each `$margins` and `$sides`, and will generate the below CSS classes:

```
.m-t-10 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.m-r-10 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.m-b-10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.m-l-10 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.m-t-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.m-r-20 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.m-b-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.m-l-20 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

That's the one way when you want only for specific values, but if you want to create margin class for 0-20, you can loop thru 0 to 20 as shown below:

```
@mixin generate-margin(){
  @for $margin from 1 through 20{
    @each $side in $sides{
      @include margin-class($side, $margin);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you write complete syntax? Like, Can I use margin-bottom: {$number}px inside the braces?

Comment: Updated my answer. To substitute any value you have to use interpolation.

Comment: Not working. I gave a class m-b-60 to a div.  after compilation, margin is not getting applied to the element.  My sass version is 3.4.24

Comment: Could you share your sass and html? Have you checked in inspector window? What is `class name` written in generated CSS file?

Comment: As you already assigned 20 to the variable $number, .m-b-20 class is getting generated in css file. Also, margin-bottom: 20px is also getting generated. 
But my HTML has class name m-b-60. I want .m-b-60 {margin-bottom: 60px} to be generated dynamically.

Comment: That's just an example, you could change the `$number` var to 60. updated my code with value 60

Comment: No, My question is not that. I don't want to assign any value to the $number. When I give a class name <div class="m-b-60"></div> <div class="m-b-50"></div> like that.. It should work for all those with out assigning any value to the $number variable.

Comment: You should build a mixin for that in combination with what @PawanKumar suggested.

Comment: I only change them in HTML m-b-30, m-b-40, m-b-50. I may have n number of classes in HTML. The SASS should capture the $number value from the class name and apply the margin accordingly.

Comment: You should mention all these details in question itself.
Yes you could use mixins with `list` of all the combinations of `class` you wanted to use in `div`

Comment: If you want it to capture whatever margin you want, I don't really see the benefit over inline style except being more compact. If you something that dynamic, you're better of using javascript.

Comment: I suggest you to read more about SASS then, as SASS is used to create complex css, re-usability. It can't read your html and create a class automatically.

Comment: Thanks @sniels, and PawanKumar I just wanted to know the possibilities with SASS.

Comment: This is probably as dynamic as you can get it in Sass. As long as you predefine what margins and sides are useful for your classes, this should work fine. [SassFiddle](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a82ba4a631728b5dfec7cf6295b9a74f)

Comment: Great @sniels. Thanks for the support.
@raghuveer999 you could try what Sniels shows in fiddle, just change the `$margins` and `$sides` lists according to you.

Comment: This is a magnificent result! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else facing this issue, here is how one can achieve this:-

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .mb-#{$i} {
     margin-bottom: #{$i}rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: This was such an easy option to generate N classes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: no it is not possible. SASS is just a language to pre-generate CSS for you. There is no on-demand, dynamic creation of classes triggered by the contents of your HTML markup. When it comes time for the browser to render your HTML and apply your specified classes, it is still just using CSS. I.e. if you assign `class="m-b-50"` to an element, the class `.m-b-50` must already be explicitly defined somewhere. As noted in the other answers, SASS can make it easier to generate a bunch of pre-defined classes but you must know which values you want to support up front.

Now, you could generate classes for some very large, all-inclusive range like `-1000` to `1000` to effectively support all values you might ever try to use and it would seem to do what you wanted, but you would be forcing your users to download a larger CSS file with, most likely, a large percentage of it being unused CSS which is wasteful and can be inconsiderate in a world of paid & limited data plans.